# URL reload issue using "ionic serve"

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Since I migrated my Ionic 2 project to Ionic 3, I seem to have an issue with `ionic serve` and rebuilding the project.

When I first build the project, everything works as expected. But I notice that the URL bar of the browser jumps to something like `localhost:8100/#/home.page/tabs/t0/tab-0/feed.page`. Before it never did that, it just showed `localhost:8100` and nothing else.

My app logic is: There is a menu that changes the `home.page` part, and there is a tabbar within the `home.page` which navigates to the first tab `feed.page`.

**Issue 1**: Before the migration, I have never seen any URL changes when browsing in the application.

**Issue 2**: After working in my code, the Ionic CLI automatically rebuilds the code as usual. Then it should in fact show the same page as before, but it doesn't. The parent menu of `home.page` is suddenly hidden and only the `feed.page` with its content is shown. Everything outside the feed page is gone.

---

Why is that happening and what I can I do about it? It is probably just a configuration, but I cannot find out where.

Comment: can you share an error message ?

Comment: There is no error, it simply does not show the menu... It shows the feed.page view as if it were independant.

Comment: As my experience i suggest you to delete pages folder which created when you started project (backup your project first). Then try `ionic generate page home` it using lazy load , more fastest and more easier to use without import page file . Also you can generate tabs automatically with tabs item & navigation using `ionic generate ` choose tabs , and fill how many tabs as you want and name it. Your page is done

Comment: That does not seem to be helpful @Reza. This issue has to do with lazy loading of the modules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of investigation, I have finally found the issue.

**Scenario 1:**

If you load `localhost:8100/` in the browser, the application gets launched as expected.

**Scenario 2:**

If you load `localhost:8100/#/home.page/tabs/t0/tab-0/feed.page`, then all involved and lazy loaded pages were actually loaded twice and finally "killing" off the menu.

What I do know now:

- I manually used `this.nav.setRoot(HomePage)` in my app's constructor
- This made all constructors load twice instead of once
- This was the reason for my issues with the menu

What I do not know:

- Why does the menu get killed if the page constructors get called twice?
- Why and how is the `HomePage`constructor called based on the URL?

**Here is a workaround:**

Using this in the constructor of my app, the `HomePage` does not get constructed a second time if it already has been constructed:

```
if (this.nav.getActive() instanceof ViewController === false || this.nav.getActive().name !== "HomePage") {
    this.nav.setRoot("HomePage");
}
```